# Remove the Remainders

Tags: package-management, antergos

Recently I installed wine, directly from the package manager (pamac). After uninstalling it again (via pamac, as well) there still remained its installation folder, with a size of 680 MB:

[image: .wine installation]

As you can see, wine is already uninstalled:

[image: wine uninstalled]

---

- Why is it, that there remains so much unneeded data after removing the corresponding software?
- How can I check, if there are more remainders from other already uninstalled software?
- Can I just delete the remained folders?

I'm using the newest version of Antergos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`system.reg`, `user.reg` and `userdef.reg` are the contents of Windows Registry for your Wine-based Windows instance. Likewise, `drive_c` has everything you put into "Windows C: drive" when you ran Wine. If you installed some Windows software, it will still be in there, taking up space.

None of these files came from packages managed by `pamac`. For it, all these are just "user files", similar to `~/.bashrc` or any other files you have in your home directory. When you remove a package, it does not automatically mean also removing *everything you created with that package* too: that would be silly.

Package managers usually deal with three categories of files:

- packaged application components
- configuration files
- other files

Packaged application components are not generally expected to be changed by anyone, other than by replacing a package with a newer version. So they are always safe to remove: if the application is needed again, just reinstalling the (exact same version of) package again will bring those same files back, guaranteed.

Configuration files are tricky: many of those come with packages, but the user (or sysadmin) is expected to make changes to them. So, when a package is removed, it is not always a good idea to remove the configuration files.

Debian's package manager handles this by having two types of removal operations: **remove** leaves all the configuration files exactly as they were, so that the configuration can be maintained even if an application is uninstalled and later reinstalled. The other type is **purge** which will also remove the configuration files.

RPM-based packaging tools use a different strategy: when removing a package, they detect whether its configuration files have been modified or not. If the configuration files still contain the package's standard default configuration, the files will be automatically removed. But if they have been modified, they will be renamed with a `.rpmsave` suffix and not removed.

I don't know how Arch's package manager deals with configuration files, but it will probably be something similar.

The third category, "other files", includes all the data files the users of the computer system have created. The package manager has no clue about the importance of any of those files. If the package manager deletes any of those, there is a high risk of the author of that package manager being the target of lawsuits and outright threats for violence and death by enraged users. So any even minimally competent package manager will leave those files well alone.

Sure, when you've removed Wine, you can remove `~/.wine` and everything it contains. But before you do that, it will be your responsibility to ensure you did not e.g. leave the only up-to-date copy of `MY_THESIS.DOCX` on the Wine desktop, or anything like that.

If you keep the `~/.wine` directory, you can later re-install Wine and have all the Windows applications and configurations you installed in the Wine environment still available. If you remove the directory, **everything you placed into the Wine-based Windows environment will be gone.** If you later re-install Wine, you get a "factory default" Wine environment again.

Comment: Yes, Arch Linux's package manager, `pacman`, behaves similarly to the RPM-based tools: when removing a package it appends `.pacsave` to the name of *edited* configuration files and leaves them where they are, unless it is invoked with the `--nosave` option - then it removes edited configuration files too.